# PCIe lanes for NVMe Memory

Tags: ssd, pci-express, nvme

I have a NVMe IC which has 2 PCIe lanes. My processor supports only 1 PCIe lane. Can I connect this NVMe memory to my processor? Will it work properly with less bandwidth?
What are the downsides and implications?

Comment: Did you check the manual for the IC? Are you talking about an actual IC (integrated circuit)? If so how does general memory relate to it? If it is an actual IC this might be more of a electronics question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it will work. However, whether or not it will work depends on the NVMe's controller and firmware.

I'd expect most NVMe controllers to also work in single-lane mode, because that's not that rare a configuration.